I have downloaded kitti dataset the labels are both in string and float format I cannot covert into float as it has 7000 images and labels
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/EDykLa1Z.png)
train: /content/drive/MyDrive/My Courses/data/train/images
val: /content/drive/MyDrive/My Courses/data/valid/images

nc: 9
names: ['Car', 'Pedestrain', 'Van', 'Cyclist', 'Truck','Train','Person_sitting','Tram','Misc','DontCare']


i want to convert string to float
